# Limit of Ordinary Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits, infinity

I have the following differential equation:

> $$ y'(t) + ay(t) = de^{-bt} $$

with $a,b,d$ constants and $a,b>0$ and I need to calculate:

$$\lim_{t\to \infty} y(t)$$
(hint consider a is not equal to b, and a equals b separately, a hint the book gives)

**ATTEMPT**:

So far I have found the general solution:

$$ y = de^{-at} \left(\frac{e^{t(a-b)}}{a-b} + C \right )$$

I am confused about how to take the limit of the problem? Do I plug in infinity where all the $t$'s are and solve for $C$ (constant from integration)? I am not sure where to go..

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you know how to use the Laplace transform to solve this DE? Given $Y(s)$ as the transform,  you can follow using the final value theorem.

Comment: Write explicitly the multiplication. Then you have a sum of two terms, one containing $e^{-bt}$ and one containing $e^{-at}$. Since $a,b>0$, both terms go to $0$ when $t\to\infty$

Comment: is the star for multiplication or is it for something else ?

Comment: Star is for multiplication.

Comment: Ok Lane I edited your question. You don't really need to write a star for multiplication.

Comment: The constant c has an exponential at the denominator so the c fraction at infinity is zero

Answer (score 1):

As Andrei wrote in the comment rewrite $y(t)$ as:

For $(a \ne b)$:
$$y(t) = de^{-at} \left(\frac{e^{t(a-b)}}{a-b} + C \right )$$
$$y(t) = \frac d{e^{bt}(a-b)} + \frac C {e^{at}}$$
Plug infinity in the expression to calculate the limit. ( don't forget that $a,b > 0)$. The result should be zero. Since both $a,b >0$.

For $a=b$:
$$y′(t)+ay(t)=de^{-at}$$
$$(y(t)e^{at})'=d$$
$$y(t)e^{at}=dt+C$$
$$y(t)=\frac {dt+C}{e^{at}}$$
You have a polynomial at the numerator and an exponential at the denominator $(a>0)$ so the limit is zero at infinity.
$$\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}\{y(t)\}=0$$

Comment: For the second part, when a = b, how come you can't use the general solution to solve this like you did for when a is not equal to b?

Comment: You have zero ( if $a=b$) at the denominator in your solution thats why the Differential Equation  has another solution in this case. And your textbook says to treat both cases differently @LaneDillon